# Sequelize: original: Error: Unknown column '' in 'field list' when include model without `attributes` field

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql, typescript, sequelize.js

Im trying to use Sequelize for MySQL queries, in my code I defined my Models and links them with his respective associations.

Trying to simulate a music playlist that have:
Artists, they can have multiples songs.

Playlist, has multiples songs too.

Songs, they are part of 1 or multiple playlists and have 1 or multiple artists.

That models are defines like this:

> In each model I defined a interface with his respective fields for safe type and comfort

ARTIST

```
export interface IArtist {
    ID_ARTIST: number,
    NAME: string
}

export const Artist = seq.define<Model<IArtist>>("Artist", {
    ID_ARTIST: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    NAME: DataTypes.STRING(30)
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: true,
    updatedAt: false,
    tableName: "ARTISTS",
})
```

PLAYLIST

```
export interface IPlaylist {
    ID_PLAYLIST: number,
    NAME: string
}

export const PlayList = seq.define<Model<IPlaylist>>("Playlist", {
    ID_PLAYLIST: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    NAME: DataTypes.STRING(20)
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: true,
    updatedAt: false,
    tableName: "PLAYLISTS"
})
```

SONG

```
export interface ISong {
    ID_SONG: number,
    ID_ARTIST: number,
    ID_PLAYLIST: number,
    DURATION: number,
    NAME: string
}

export const Song = seq.define<Model<ISong>>("Song", {
    ID_SONG: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    ID_ARTIST: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: Artist,
            key: "ID_ARTIST"
        }
    },
    ID_PLAYLIST: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: PlayList,
            key: "ID_PLAYLIST"
        }
    },
    DURATION: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    NAME: DataTypes.STRING(40)
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    updatedAt: false,
    tableName: "SONGS"
})
```

And the relations of each table:

```
Artist.hasMany(Song)
PlayList.hasMany(Song)
Song.belongsTo(Artist, { foreignKey: "ID_ARTIST" })
Song.belongsTo(PlayList, { foreignKey: "ID_PLAYLIST" })
```

Then when I try to do a 'findAll' operation like this:

```
const query = await Song.findAll({
      include: {
        model: Artist,
        required: true
      },
      where: {
        ID_ARTIST: idArtist
      }
    })
```

> idArtist is a function parameter -> idArtist: string

I get the next error:
sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'Song.ArtistIDARTIST' in 'field list'"

And the query result from sequelize:
sql: "SELECT `Song`.`ID_SONG`, `Song`.`ID_ARTIST`, `Song`.`ID_PLAYLIST`, `Song`.`DURATION`, `Song`.`NAME`, `Song`.`createdAt`, `Song`.`ArtistIDARTIST`, `Song`.`PlaylistIDPLAYLIST`, `Artist`.`ID_ARTIST` AS `Artist.ID_ARTIST`, `Artist`.`NAME` AS `Artist.NAME`, `Artist`.`createdAt` AS `Artist.createdAt` FROM `SONGS` AS `Song` INNER JOIN `ARTISTS` AS `Artist` ON `Song`.`ID_ARTIST` = `Artist`.`ID_ARTIST` WHERE `Song`.`ID_ARTIST` = '1';"

Why sequelize tries to get an nonexistent column like Song.PlaylistIDPLAYLIST or Song.ArtistIDARTIST when not use 'attributes' field in findAll or similar methods

Thanks in advance, if other info is needed tell me :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define paired associations with the same `foreignKey` option, see my [answer here](https://f95zone.to/threads/the-hellcat-lounge-v0-3-01-wilson-wonka.125509/)